# Request a 2nd url with the same HttpWebRequest obj

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I want to do something like this

```
{
    HttpWebRequest WebRequestObject = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://google.com");
    WebRequestObject.KeepAlive = true;
    //do stuff
    WebRequestObject.Something("http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif");
    //more here
}
```

How do i keep the connection alive and go to multiple urls using that same alive connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply use another `HttpWebRequest` object and provided that you set `KeepAlive` to `true` in both cases the internal HTTP connection manager in the .NET Framework should handle things for you. See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive.aspx) for the `KeepAlive` property for more info on this.

Comment: Also, if you want to confirm this, just use a packet analyser such as Wireshark to monitor your HTTP traffic.